# Passing parameters to global shared library - constructor

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a simple problem:
I have a global (non-sandbox) `/src` library - `utils`
I need to pass parameters to utils on construction

```groovy
@Library("Woop")
def utils = new a.b.c.d.Utils(Script::this)
```

works and the script reference is deposited in:

```groovy
public class Utils implements Serializable {
    Script script
```

if I try to add a parameter:

```groovy
@Library("Woop")
def utils = new a.b.c.d.Utils(Script::this, 3)
```

and change Utils to add the int

```groovy
public class Utils implements Serializable {
    Script script
    int three
```

I get:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
unclassified new a.b.c.d.Utils java.util.LinkedHashMap java.lang.Integer
```

I am uncertain as to how to **pass** multiple parameters, and how to **accept** multiple parameters. All I can do is GUESS, which is amazingly inefficient and frustrating.

### Bonus Question

given a folder library `\vars\Abc.Groovy`, accessed through `@Library('Project') _` how can I pass this library to a shared global library?
Assuming we solve the initial problem, do I just call

```groovy
new a.b.c.d.Utils(Script::this, Abc)
```

or

`new a.b.c.d.Utils(Script::this, Abc.class)`?
How is it supposed to be defined in the Utils class?

I'm unclear because `Abc` is supposed to be a static instance of the `class Abc`, so I'm confused here... :-(

The Jenkins documentation is so bad, it's embarrassing. Normally, passing parameters to constructors is something that you'd expect be documented...

Comment: Are you trying to call the named argument constructor? Shouldn't that be `new a.b.c.d.Utils(script: this, three: Abc)`?

Comment: About you bonus question: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Please open a dedicated question with some example.

Comment: I figured it out, you have to pass it as `Abc.class` and pass it properly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no pipeline or cpsLibrary issue. To call a contstructor in groovy using named arguments you have to use:

```groovy
new a.b.c.d.Utils(script: this, three: Abc)
```

Although so far I never used named arguments in cps code I just tried and it works.
See also:
[Groovy could not find matching constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408641/groovy-could-not-find-matching-constructor?rq=1)

Comment: thanks! chalk it to my being a Java dev... Groovy is, ugh

Answer (score 0):

It might work if you change:

```
int three
```

to

```
Integer three
```

In your Utils class.  Otherwise I would try explicitly adding the constructor, like so:

```
Utils(Script s, Integer i) { 
    script = s
    three = i
}
```

Comment: I'll try this later, thanks! See if it works for me :-)