# Could not find matching constructor for anonymous class

Tags: groovy

Consider the following code sample

```
class A {
  int data
}


class B extends A {}
def o1 = new B(data: 1)
// This works correctly.


def o2 = new A(data:1) {}
// This will throw the following error
// Exception thrown
//
// groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: A(LinkedHashMap)
//  at ConsoleScript2$1.<init>(ConsoleScript2)
//  at ConsoleScript2.run(ConsoleScript2:11)
//  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
//  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
//  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

To me, the anonymous one should be the same as the named class. But it turns out that Groovy treats them differently. I want to know how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408641/groovy-could-not-find-matching-constructor might help

Comment: It's a different issue to me, my question is about anonymous class.

Comment: You can file an issue ticket with Apache Groovy project if you think this syntax should be supported for AIC. You can also use an object initializer block in the AIC body to set any properties or other initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see this error because of the nature of the dynamic map constructor - it is not added explicitly to the generated classes, but it is called through the `CallSite.callConstructor(obj,map)` method instead. However, there is a solution to that problem.

Consider the following exemplary `test.groovy` script:

```
class A {
    int data
}

class B extends A {}

def a1 = new B(data: 1)
def a2 = new A(data: 2) {}

println a1
println a2
```

When you decompile generated `A.class` file, you will something like this:

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by FernFlower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import groovy.transform.Generated;
import groovy.transform.Internal;
import java.beans.Transient;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class A implements GroovyObject {
    private int data;

    @Generated
    public A() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        super();
        MetaClass var2 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var2;
    }

    @Generated
    @Internal
    @Transient
    public MetaClass getMetaClass() {
        MetaClass var10000 = this.metaClass;
        if (var10000 != null) {
            return var10000;
        } else {
            this.metaClass = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
            return this.metaClass;
        }
    }

    @Generated
    @Internal
    public void setMetaClass(MetaClass var1) {
        this.metaClass = var1;
    }

    @Generated
    public int getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    @Generated
    public void setData(int var1) {
        this.data = var1;
    }
}
```

This class has only one no-args constructor. When you decompile the `test.class` file (compiled Groovy script file), you will see something like this:

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by FernFlower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.Script;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class test extends Script {
    public test() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        super();
    }

    public test(Binding context) {
        CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
        super(context);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        var1[0].call(InvokerHelper.class, test.class, args);
    }

    public Object run() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        Object a1 = var1[1].callConstructor(B.class, ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(new Object[]{"data", 1}));
        Object a2 = new test.1(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(new Object[]{"data", 2}));
        var1[2].callCurrent(this, a1);
        return var1[3].callCurrent(this, a2);
    }

    public class 1 extends A {
    }
}
```

Take a look at how objects `a1` and `a2` are initialized. The `a1` object is initialized in the following way:

```java
Object a1 = var1[1].callConstructor(B.class, ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(new Object[]{"data", 1}));
```

It uses the `CallSite.callConstructor()` method to mimic the map constructor which does not exist in the `A` class. If we look at how the object `a2` is initialized we will find this:

```java
Object a2 = new test.1(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(new Object[]{"data", 2}));
```

We can see that Groovy in the case of the anonymous class (which is not anonymous at all - Groovy generates a class anyway), Groovy uses a direct constructor call. And it fails, because there is no `A(LinkedHashMap)` constructor in the parent class.

#### Solution

Luckily, there is a solution to this problem - you can use `@MapConstructor` and `@InheritConstructors` annotations to force creating map constructor in the `A` class, and to inherit this constructor in the `B` class. Take a look at this working example:

```
import groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
import groovy.transform.MapConstructor

@MapConstructor
class A {
    int data
}

@InheritConstructors
class B extends A {}

def a1 = new B(data: 1)
def a2 = new A(data: 2) {}

println a1
println a2
```

The only requirement is to use at least the Groovy 2.5 version which introduced the `@MapConstructor` annotation.

Comment: Thank you so much @szymon-stepniak You not only solve my problem but also offer a new idea to decompile the class file to investigate the problem.

I have tried add `@MapConstructor` before but it didn't work, I didn't aware that `@ InheritConstructors` is also required.

The minimal runnable sample would be like 

```groovy
import groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
import groovy.transform.MapConstructor

@InheritConstructors
@MapConstructor
class A {
    int data
}

def a = new A(data: 1) {}

println a.data
```

Comment: If you use only a single `A` class, the `@InheritConstructors` is not required. The only reason it is required in the class `B` is the fact that it implements a non-args constructor, and thus it needs to inherit the map constructor explicitly. The class that gets generated to play the role of the anonymous class has no constructor defined, so it will inherit all constructors from the `A` class by default.

Comment: I see. I didn't expect that introduce class B may have this unexpected side-effect when I try to find out a solution by doing experiments.